# PYTHON - Unhashable List

Tags: python, model-view-controller, list, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to display some information in a GUI list-box. I have written a test method in a model only portion of my MVC which outputs the information I want; however, when I transfer that code to my full GUI, it throws me an error.

**Here are the two pieces of code:**

**Model:** (note that this method is written for a class `Products()`)

```
def test(self):
    for key in self._items_list:
        print self.get_item(key) #this refers to the get_item function of the Products class:

def get_item(self, key):
    return self._items_list[key] # items_list is a dictionary
```

So, this returns the output I would like to put in my list-box.

**Here is how I transfer the code to my GUI** (this is in a class i defined which inherits from Listbox):

```
def refreshData(self):
    for keys in self._productslist: #this productslist is equivalent to items_list
        disp = self._products.get_item(keys) #so i can call the method from the Product class
        self.insert(END, dips)
```

This throws me the following error when I try to open and display the file:

```
...in get_item
return self._items_list[key]
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Sorry, this is long and probably very confusing, but essentially I want to know why I get the error for the method in the full version of the code and not in the isolated model.

All the relevant code is identical as far as I know.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Lists cannot be used as keys in dictionaries or values in sets because they do not support hashing - this is a design decision Python has enforced (presumably because lists are mutable and this can lead to nasty surprises).

Comment: (Check the what `key` evaluates to - it might not be as expected - then *search* for the error message and link the two things together :-)

Comment: but why wouldnt there be an error in the isolated model code? thats what is confusing to me!
also, the "list" is a dictionary i called self._items_list, so i am calling the value of the dictionary stored at the [key]. yeah?

Comment: @pst i think im heading in the right direction, thanks. still not sorted but i think i get what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

You can't hash lists, only immutable things.  Although you could define a `__hash__` method for some extension of the `list` object, the reason behind this logic is that if you were to look something up in a dictionary, you would expect the entries' names not to change.  Similarly, in python, the keys must be immutable.  As another answer said, use a `tuple` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use tuples instead:
http://wiki.python.org/moin/DictionaryKeys